Les propositions double-subordonnées
Est-il possible d'écrire quelque chose comme « Je doute qu’il faille que vous restiez trop tard au bureau. » dans le français littéraire ?
Est-ce utilisé dans la langue orale ?


Oui, ça me semble possible même si les exemples ne sont pas légion.


Voyager est sans doute une fort bonne chose, mais je doute qu'il faille que les dîners en ville soient de la partie.
Pierre-Jean de Béranger, Correspondance, 1860.

Quelque chose d'approchant :

Il y a donc quelque chose que tu ne veux pas me montrer qu’il faille que je sois partie pour que tu les ouvres !
Georges Feydeau, Le système Ribadier, 1948.


Oui , c'est possible aussi. On peut aussi reformuler par exemple comme ceci :


Je ne pense pas qu'il soit nécessaire que vous restiez trop tard au bureau.

Note: le ne explétif est rarement présent avec ce type de phrase et le verbe douter (je doute qu'il ne faille...), mais est fréquent avec le verbe craindre.


Bonne trouvaille, ce ne explétif! Je n'y aurais pas pensé...

Merci beaucoup!

Je n'avais pas vu « être légion » utilisé pour signifié être nombreux avant cela. Je crois qu'on trouverait ce Ngram interessant. Il nous montre l'utilisation de « qu'il (ne) faille » sans filtrer le verbe principal.

C'est grammaticalement correct, mais sans doute plutôt rare, voire très rare, dans la langue orale contemporaine et quotidienne. Pour ce qui est du style, la répétition de ces deux que n'est peut-être pas très heureuse.
Sans prétendre à un très bon style, mais simplement pour éviter ces que et ces temps compliqués, on pourrait avoir recours en langue orale de tous les jours à une tournure (incorrecte du point de vue des temps) comme: Je doute que vous serez forcé de rester très tard au bureau.

Vous pouvez utiliser des quantités de constructions de cette sorte. Elles sont normales avec « douter (que) » et « falloir », bien sûr, mais plus généralement les combinaisons suivantes ne posent aucun problème :

toutes les formes verbales construites avec  « que » suivies d'une forme verbale construite avec » que »
toutes les formes verbales construites avec  « que » suivies d'un adjectif construit avec « que + prop. »,
tous les adjectifs construits avec « que » suivis d'un adjectif  qui appelle la conjonction « que » ou de « fait + que ».
(Liste pas nécessairement exhaustive)

Les combinaison sont possibles au libre choix du locuteur. (Il est laissé au lecteur  de reconnaitre les catégories dans les exemples ci-dessous.)

Je doute qu’il faille que vous restiez trop tard au bureau.

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille que vous compreniez d'abord cette partie. (ne se dit pas à la forme affirmative)

Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il faille que vous alliez d'abord au bureau de l'immigration. (ne se dit pas à la forme affirmative)

Je pense qu'il est nécessaire que le poteau soit très droit.

Jean s'est rendu compte qu'il est important qu'il n'y ait pas de saleté.

Le maire dit qu'il est rare que les gens se plaignent du mauvais état des routes de campagne.

Je doute qu'il soit nécessaire que vous alliez les voir.

Elle savait qu'il ignorait le fait qu'elle connaissait bien ça.

Ils apprirent qu'il fallait qu'elle revienne.

Le secrétaire savait qu'il était temps qu' il parte.



Je pense qu'il faille est très moche, je suis sûr qu'il faille est encore pire...

@jlliagre On dirait que ça ne peut aller qu'à la forme négative.
